In Lubuntu 22.04.5 LTs whit LXQT 0.17.0 Isnt' possible to use any other web browser, only Google Chrome or Konqueror
Although you can install Chromium and its derivatives, as well as the famous Firefox, among many others, many, except Google Chrome, Opera and Konqueror, are the only browsers that can run perfectly when installed.
What could be the reason for this situation?

What does "run perfectly" mean to you?  Can you give examples of unperfect running in your question?

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read How do I ask a good question? And provide us more details. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your question makes little sense to me; whilst I'm mostly mostly later releases, I've had no issues with any browser I've tried on Lubuntu 22.04 LTS (default LXQt), which includes chromium, firefox, lynx, w3m (tor-browser awhile but haven't used that in some time on jammy) etc...

There is a new LTS release of Lubuntu, Noble numbat (a little striped marsupial in danger of extinction). You could try "sudo do-release-upgrade" to install it. I don't know whether this would fix your problem but it might.
